# SELECT:ing a row with a id blob using a parameterized query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite database where all rows have a UUID as the primary key, the db column is defined as a BLOB.

The keys are inserted as byte[] instead of Strings to avoid wasting [storage and index spaces](http://wtanaka.com/node/8106). I can insert, update and delete rows using SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement and using bindBlob on the SQLiteStatement but I can't find anyway to bind a blob to the parameters of a SELECT query.

Both SQLiteDatabase.query and .rawQuery expects my WHERE arguments to be Strings which will never match my byte array blobs. I can find my row if I construct my WHERE manually using a BLOB literal like this:

```
final Cursor query = db.query(getTableName(),
                              getColumns(),
                              "id = X'" + bytesToHex(getByteArrayFromUUID(id)) + "'" ,
                              null,
                              null,
                              null,
                              null);
```

But then I am vulnerable to SQL injections...

In every other language I have used SQLite in this is not a problem, is there really no way to get a standard prepared SELECT statement with android SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the APIs in Android sqlite expect the parameter to be strings.

You can use [`compileStatement()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String)) to prepare your query and then use [`bindBlob()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindBlob(int,%20byte[])) to bind a blob argument to it. Getting useful results out from the query is not easy though, [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) has methods for only a few 1x1 result sets.

On the other hand, using a blob as a key doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: compileStatement() does not return a response / cursor so it can't be used to execute SELECT queries.

Comment: "On the other hand, using a blob as a key doesn't seem like a good idea." The client have to generate a unique ID without talking to the server so we can't use a INT id, instead we use a UUID. We can store the UUID as TEXT but that will just waste space since the binary BLOB representation only occupies 16 bytes.